# Heroku rollback application goes down

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

When i did my ruby on rails app rollback on heroku, the application go down. How to fixed it? http://ezgo-test.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check logs and paste in the specific error, you can do as below.

```
heroku logs --tail --app app-name
```

As per your problem "No web processes running". you can fix it as below.

```
heroku ps:scale web=1 --app app-name
```

As per heroku documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running .

Comment: 2016-08-09T14:06:47.576041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=ezgo-test.herokuapp.com request_id=4b7b51e7-2b92-4aa3-beba-776113744b16 fwd="84.22.47.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Are you on hobby version or paid one heroku ? In any case you can fix it via https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running